How can I correctly manage memory block allocation in C without overwriting the main block?
I am working on a C project where the goal is to manage memory blocks using dynamic memory allocation function such as realloc and malloc and store their state in a file called block.dat. The main memory block (which represents the total available memory) is stored in this file, and it should be rewritten each time more memory blocks are allocated to processes. When allocating memory, the main block should be reduced in size, and new blocks representing the assigned memory to processes should be added.
Expected Output:
When I allocate memory to a process, I aim to:
Reduce the size of the main block.
Create a new block representing the memory assigned to the process.
Save the updated state of memory in the ```block.dat``` file.

The expected content in block.dat after assigning memory to a process should look like this:
Name: MainBlock
Size: 6000000 bytes
State: Free
Block 1:
Name: Block1
Size: 2000000 bytes
Process assigned: Process_2
State: Occupied

Code Implementation:
I implemented the MemoryBlock structure to represent each memory block in the system, including both the main memory block and any additional blocks created for processes. The structure stores key information such as the block's name, its size, the process assigned to it (if any), and whether the block is free or occupied:
typedef struct {
    char name[50];       // Block name (e.g., "MainBlock", "Block1", etc.)
    int size;            // Size of the block in bytes
    char process[50];    // Process name assigned to the block (if any)
    int free;            // 1 if free, 0 if occupied
} MemoryBlock;

This structure is defined as follows:
init_block  ** function to initialize the main block: **
void init_block(MemoryBlock **memory, int *used_blocks) {
    
    //Helper function that execute a sysinfo process to get available memory in system, and assign into main memory block size.
 
    long available_memory = get_avilable_memory();
    *memory = (MemoryBlock *)malloc(sizeof(MemoryBlock));  // Reserve space for the memory block
    (*memory)->size = available_memory;  // Initialize the main block with 8 MB
    (*memory)->free = 1;  // Block is free
    strcpy((*memory)->name, "MainBlock");
    strcpy((*memory)->process, "None");  // No process assigned

    *used_blocks = 0;  // No blocks assigned yet

    // Save the initial state of the block to the block.dat file
    save_block_state(*memory, *used_blocks);

    printf("Memory initialized:\nName: %s\nSize: %d bytes\nState: Free\n", (*memory)->name, (*memory)->size);
}

Function to save the block state:
void save_block_state(MemoryBlock *memory, int used_blocks) {
    FILE *file = fopen("block.dat", "w");  // Open the file in write mode
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening block.dat");
        return;
    }

    // Save the main block
    fprintf(file, "Name: %s\n", memory[0].name);
    fprintf(file, "Size: %d bytes\n", memory[0].size);
    fprintf(file, "State: %s\n", memory[0].free ? "Free" : "Occupied");

    // Save the assigned blocks
    for (int i = 1; i <= used_blocks; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "Block %d:\n", i);
        fprintf(file, "Name: %s\n", memory[i].name);
        fprintf(file, "Size: %d bytes\n", memory[i].size);
        fprintf(file, "Process assigned: %s\n", memory[i].process);
        fprintf(file, "State: Occupied\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
    printf("Memory state saved successfully to block.dat.\n");
}

Function to load the block memory state:
void load_block_state(MemoryBlock **memory, int *used_blocks) {
    FILE *file = fopen("block.dat", "r");
    if (file == NULL || fgetc(file) == EOF) {  // If the file does not exist or is empty
        printf("The block.dat file does not exist or is empty. Initializing memory as new.\n");
        init_block(memory, used_blocks);  // Initialize the block if no state is found
        if (file != NULL) fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    rewind(file);  // Rewind to the start of the file if it is not empty

    // Read the main block
    *memory = (MemoryBlock *)malloc(sizeof(MemoryBlock));
    fscanf(file, "Name: %s\n", (*memory)->name);
    fscanf(file, "Size: %d bytes\n", &(*memory)->size);
    char state[10];
    fscanf(file, "State: %s\n", state);
    (*memory)->free = (strcmp(state, "Free") == 0) ? 1 : 0;

    // Read the assigned blocks
    int block_index = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "Block %d:\n", &block_index) == 1) {
        (*memory) = (MemoryBlock *)realloc(*memory, (block_index + 1) * sizeof(MemoryBlock));

        char block_name[50];
        int block_size;
        char process_name[50];

        // Read the block data
        fscanf(file, "Name: %s\n", block_name);
        fscanf(file, "Size: %d bytes\n", &block_size);
        fscanf(file, "Process assigned: %s\n", process_name);
        fscanf(file, "State: Occupied\n");

        // Assign the read data to the block
        (*memory)[block_index - 1].size = block_size;
        strcpy((*memory)[block_index - 1].name, block_name);
        strcpy((*memory)[block_index - 1].process, process_name);
        (*memory)[block_index - 1].free = 0;
    }

    *used_blocks = block_index;
    fclose(file);
}

assign_block implementation for allocating memory blocks:
void assign_block(MemoryBlock **memory, int *used_blocks) {
     
    //Helper function that open a "ps" process to get a list of process with their PID, Names and Memory usage
    get_total_process(); 
   
    printf("Total available memory in the main block: %d bytes\n", (*memory)[0].size);

    FILE *file = fopen("processes.dat", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening processes.dat");
        return;
    }

    printf("Processes available for memory assignment:\nProcess   | Memory Usage\n");
    printf("--------------------------\n");
    char line[256];
    int process_index = 1;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        printf("(%d) %s", process_index, line);
        process_index++;
    }
    fclose(file);

    int process_choice;
    printf("Enter the number corresponding to the process to assign the memory block to: ");
    scanf("%d", &process_choice);

    int block_size;
    printf("How many bytes of memory do you want to assign to the selected process?: ");
    scanf("%d", &block_size);

    if (block_size > (*memory)[0].size) {
        printf("Error: Not enough memory in the main block.\n");
        return;
    }

    (*memory)[0].size -= block_size;

    *memory = (MemoryBlock *)realloc(*memory, (*used_blocks + 2) * sizeof(MemoryBlock));

    MemoryBlock *new_block = &(*memory)[*used_blocks + 1];
    new_block->size = block_size;
    new_block->free = 0;
    sprintf(new_block->name, "Block%d", *used_blocks + 1);
    sprintf(new_block->process, "Process_%d", process_choice);

    (*used_blocks)++;
    save_block_state(*memory, *used_blocks);

    printf("Assigned %d bytes to Process_%d.\n", block_size, process_choice);
    printf("Remaining size in MainBlock: %d bytes\n", (*memory)[0].size);
}

main that implements assign_block:
int main() {
    MemoryBlock *memory = NULL;
    int used_blocks = 0;

    // Load the memory state from block.dat
    load_block_state(&memory, &used_blocks);

    // Assign a block to a process
    assign_block(&memory, &used_blocks);

    // Show the current memory state
    show_mem_status(memory, used_blocks);

    // Free allocated memory
    free(memory);

    return 0;
}

The output I actually got:
The issue I am facing is that when I try to assign a memory block to a process, instead of creating a new block for the process, it seems that the main block (MainBlock) is overwritten with the data of the newly assigned block. Here is the content I get in block.dat:
Name: MainBlock
Size: 2000000 bytes
State: Occupied

Additionally, when I run the show_mem_status function after assigning a block, I get the following output:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: MainBlock
Size: 2000000 bytes
State: Occupied
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

when the expected output should be:
Name: MainBlock
Size: 6000000 bytes
State: Free
Block 1:
Name: Block1
Size: 2000000 bytes
Process assigned: Process_2
State: Occupied

As you can see, instead of reducing the size of the main block and creating a new block for the assigned process, the main block is overwritten with the data from the newly assigned block. The expected behavior would be that the size of MainBlock decreases, and a new block for Process_2 is shown separately in the status output.
My question:
How can I modify my implementation to prevent the main block from being overwritten, and instead correctly add a new block for each assigned process?

In your load_block_state, you're writing to (*memory)[block_index-1].  When you're handling block 1, what is that going to overwrite?  When I fix that, your code runs correctly for me.

Why is that causing the error? I dont understand. That means is overwriting the main block?

Right.  When you load block 1, you're writing to (*memory)[0].  Where do you store your global info?  You put it in (*memory)[0].  You can't put two things in one space.

You might consider having the header be a different structure, to avoid the off-by-one confusion.  You might consider using a linked list, to avoid the realloc calls.  But that's after you get it working.

An unrelated code style concern: consider doing MemoryBlock* result = malloc(...); ... result->member = something; ... for more readable code. Then at the end when everything is done and correct, you do *memory = result; just before returning from the function. Apart from easier to read code, you also get the best practice of not modifying any pointed-at parameter before you know that there are no errors.

I figure out! I settle a conditional to rewrite the main block (*memory) [0] if the used_blocks are greater than one.
